# Retrieving JSON array in Javascript from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to return a json encoded array to JS from PHP and i've done so many times before but now i'm getting a weird error. I am successfully getting the data and it's displaying the array in chrome. However, I cannot get it to enter the AJAX success function if I specify the `dataType: 'json'`.  If I remove the dataType and use  `var parsed = JSON.parse(data);` it will enter the success function but it will throw an unexpected type error. Please help.

**Chrome output:**

```
[
    {
        "fullURL": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/--ZKG_L-SA9c/UgqECNqP4II/AAAAAAAAA2I/i5nCa3CvKqM/s912/2010raptor_firstdrive002_opt.jpg",
        "thumbURL": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/--ZKG_L-SA9c/UgqECNqP4II/AAAAAAAAA2I/i5nCa3CvKqM/s128-c/2010raptor_firstdrive002_opt.jpg",
        "location": "",
        "caption": "",
        "tags": "",
        "program_instance_id": "a0Ji0000001pPO6EAM"
    },
    {
        "fullURL": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-kyUg7_Rul90/UgqEDIu4DhI/AAAAAAAAA2Q/WF0BAEI7smo/s912/220px-Microchip_PIC24HJ32GP202.jpg",
        "thumbURL": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-kyUg7_Rul90/UgqEDIu4DhI/AAAAAAAAA2Q/WF0BAEI7smo/s128-c/220px-Microchip_PIC24HJ32GP202.jpg",
        "location": "",
        "caption": "",
        "tags": "",
        "program_instance_id": "a0Ji0000001pPO6EAM"
    }
]
```

### PHP

```
$arr = array();
foreach($photoURLS as $photo)
{
$arr[] = $photo;
}

}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

---

### JS

```
$.ajax
({
    async: "false",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {action: 'var1', albumName: 'var2'},
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/controller/function',
        success: function(data) 
        {
        //alert($.isArray(data));
        $.each(parsed, function(i, index) {
        alert(index.fullURL);
        });
        }
 });
```

Comment: This would somehow suggest that the response you get is not valid JSON. However, what you posted is valid. Are you `echo`ing anything else in your PHP script?

Comment: Why do you need to loop the urls and push them to another array? Can't you just `echo json_encode($photoURLS)`?

Comment: If you remove the `dataType` attribute, jQuery will automatically guess the data type, so perhaps you won't need to `JSON.parse` the result.

Comment: @Felix yes there are other echo's in the controller, but only 1 echo in that function which is the `json_encode($arr)`;

Comment: Try to call you controller manually, just to check the result content. May be there is more data sent and the JSON is finally not well parsed. As @Toxz says, check also that your server is sending correct json header (its a good behaviour)

Comment: Sometimes I run into these types of problems,on the PHP side I'll call `ob_clean(); echo json_encode($arr); exit();` to make sure I'm not sending anything "extra." Might be worth a shot.

Comment: @Divey that did it, not sure why but it's working now. If you want to submit that as an answer ill accept it. Also not sure why that works is there any way to check what else it was sending?

Comment: The comment provided by @Divey is really just a hack to work around bad coding you have done elsewhere.  You really should find out where and why you are outputting more to the client then you are expecting.

Comment: @Mike's correct. The problem is that you're sending extra output somewhere (perhaps spaces or newlines that you can't easily identify in your output?). Now, if you remove the `ob_clean();`, and keep the `exit();` and everything works, you know that the bad output is coming after that section of code. If you remove the `exit();` and keep the `ob_clean();` and everything works, you know the problem is before that section. That's still not the final solution, but it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

So I worked the code back and think this solution might work for you.

```
$.ajax({
  async: "false",
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    action: 'var1',
    albumName: 'var2'
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  url: '/controller/function',
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
      console.log(index);
      console.log(element.fullURL);
      console.log(element);
    });
  }
});
```

I can't test the ajax event however I have tested out the json you provided with the each loop and it seams to work. [LINK TO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GBXSw/)

```
var data = [{
    "caption": "",
        "fullURL": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/--ZKG_L-SA9c/UgqECNqP4II/AAAAAAAAA2I/i5nCa3CvKqM/s912/2010raptor_firstdrive002_opt.jpg",
        "location": "",
        "program_instance_id": "a0Ji0000001pPO6EAM",
        "tags": "",
        "thumbURL": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/--ZKG_L-SA9c/UgqECNqP4II/AAAAAAAAA2I/i5nCa3CvKqM/s128-c/2010raptor_firstdrive002_opt.jpg"
}, {
    "caption": "",
        "fullURL": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-kyUg7_Rul90/UgqEDIu4DhI/AAAAAAAAA2Q/WF0BAEI7smo/s912/220px-Microchip_PIC24HJ32GP202.jpg",
        "location": "",
        "program_instance_id": "a0Ji0000001pPO6EAM",
        "tags": "",
        "thumbURL": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-kyUg7_Rul90/UgqEDIu4DhI/AAAAAAAAA2Q/WF0BAEI7smo/s128-c/220px-Microchip_PIC24HJ32GP202.jpg"
}];

$.each(data, function (index, element) {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(element.fullURL);
});
```

also good news is that your json is 100% valid so what is being passed back seams correct. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to send the correct HTTP header with your response.
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-http-header-for-json-file

Answer (score 0):

The variable `parsed` at your `$.each` function is not defined. you should use `data` instead of `parsed` as `data` is the variable at your `success` callback function.

```
$.each(data, function(i, index) {
    alert(index.fullURL);
    });
```